# Generating permutations

Tags: python

I need to generate a list of variable length listing all possible values of a n-length tuple with each value either 0 or 1. Thus there are 2^n possible tuples. For example, for an input of n=3 my list should look like

```
a=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), 
(1, 1, 1)]
```

Note: It doesn't matter if the inner elements are tuples, use lists if convenient. It also doesn't matter much if the final list isn't sorted as per my example. I currently can do it using a for loop, but was wondering if there is some better, more pythony approach to this. This is the code I wrote.

```
>>>>newlist=[]
>>>>for i in range(2**n):
          s=bin(i)[2:] #spliced to remove the leading '0b' in the string
          s='0'*(n-len(s))+s #adding extra zeroes to beginning of string
          buffer=tuple(int(i) for i in s)
          newlist.append(buffer)
```

That generates the list I wanted. Any suggestions to do it in a better, one-liner way?

Comment: Just from the title, `itertools` is your friend.

Comment: The answer I got just now demonstrates that quite clearly :)

Comment: The canonical version of the question that was used as a duplicate before, is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905. However, we have a more specific duplicate (this is more of a "Cartesian exponent" than a Cartesian product), so I used one of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), like this

```
from itertools import product
print list(product(range(2), repeat = 3))
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: whoa. I had no idea this even existed. Thanks a lot. Need to read about the itertools module. I am going to accept this as soon as it lets me :D